# Possibility to automatically parent & position elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make certain elements w/ certain `#ids` / `.classes` be automatically parented & positioned together with matching `#ids` and/or `.classes`? I'm trying to make it so that instead of making separate images for each individual button, which would double, maybe triple the data, time, and space consumed , or using `position: absolute` because of different resolutions of monitors screwing that up, I want to be able to parent a `<p class="linkText1">` element with a `<img class="linkText1" src="URL HERE">`, so that when it does pair it up it will position the text in the center of `img`, and fix the position of the `p` element to the `img` element. Here's my code, and my attempt at writing the JavaScript for the detection.

```js
/* var pair = function()  {
  if(this.class === this.class)  {
    this.style.text-align = "center";
    this.style.position = "relative";
    this.style.position = "absolute";
    }
  }
pair(img, para);
*/
```

```css
.nav  {
  
}
.navlinks  {

}
.navlinks a  {
  font-family: "Lietz", arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #FFA500;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.news  {

}
.donate  {

}
.content  {

}
.footer  {

}
.footlinks  {

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/fonts/font.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div class="nav">
        <div class="navlinks">
          <a href="#"><img src='http://www.thegaminghideout.com/css/ButtonA.png' width='120' height='35' onmouseover="this.src='http://www.thegaminghideout.com/css/ButtonB.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.thegaminghideout.com/css/ButtonA.png';" /><p class="linkText">Link 1</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news">
        
      </div>
      <div class="donate">

      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut semper auctor nunc, ac rhoncus ligula. Nunc vel magna dignissim, finibus augue in, ultrices urna. In auctor id sapien sit amet facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus semper erat at nisi euismod facilisis. Nunc pharetra vel risus scelerisque posuere. Suspendisse malesuada magna ut faucibus consectetur.
          Aenean hendrerit fringilla lorem dictum tincidunt. Etiam libero tortor, dignissim ac consequat ut, ultricies in odio. Donec vel dui non metus lacinia vehicula ut sagittis orci. Pellentesque mauris mauris, dapibus ac sagittis a, volutpat id tortor. Donec tempor ante lobortis massa feugiat, sit amet molestie magna vestibulum. Sed hendrerit metus suscipit feugiat faucibus. Sed eget justo ligula. Morbi scelerisque sagittis sem, ut semper quam convallis lacinia. Vestibulum ac suscipit ex. Vivamus pharetra tellus ac tellus auctor, sed vestibulum enim commodo. Curabitur cursus sollicitudin eleifend. Ut tempor venenatis lacus, tristique congue libero scelerisque et. Pellentesque vehicula rhoncus orci ac dapibus. Pellentesque feugiat sem diam, ut porttitor mi accumsan sagittis.

          Mauris lectus turpis, dignissim quis sagittis ac, pellentesque sit amet felis. Vestibulum auctor ex non ullamcorper porta. Aliquam feugiat posuere arcu, nec sagittis nisl fringilla sed. Integer quis metus congue, dapibus nisl non, accumsan quam. Duis sodales, erat non varius gravida, dolor orci tempor lectus, eu egestas felis ipsum eu sem. Suspendisse vitae tellus accumsan, tempor sapien vitae, tincidunt nisl. Donec egestas neque quis orci sodales, at maximus purus posuere. Phasellus ut arcu quis mauris accumsan rhoncus. Morbi in risus non dui aliquet molestie. Quisque volutpat enim vel est vehicula laoreet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footlinks">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add more information and clear code.

Comment: remember you can also set the img as a backround property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need javascript for that, css will do it based on classes.

```css
div{border:1px solid red;}
p{border:1px solid green;}
img{opacity:0.4;}
.one{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
.two{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;}
.three{position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;}
.four{position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="one" >div one </div>
<div class="two" >div two </div>
<div class="three" >div three </div>
<div class="four" >div four </div>
<p class="one"> p one</p>
<p class="two">p two </p>
<p class="three">p three</p>
<p class="four">p four </p>
<img class="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"/>
<img class="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"/>
<img class="three" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"/>
<img class="four" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"/>
```